# It's posible to define the UDP sourceport?

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have a WinForm application made it in VB.NET and I need to answer in the same port that I receive the UDP message but with the code that I have running the application source port is being chosen by the O.S., or it seems that.

```
Private Sub UdpSend(ByVal txtMessage As String)
    Dim pRet As Integer
    GLOIP = IPAddress.Parse(IpRemotaLbl.Text)
    GLOINTPORT = RemotePortLbl.Text
    MyUdpClient.Connect(GLOIP, GLOINTPORT)
    bytCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage)
    pRet = MyUdpClient.Send(bytCommand, bytCommand.Length)
    'Console.WriteLine("No of bytes send " & pRet)
    PrintLog("No of bytes send " & pRet)
End Sub
```

In example, if I receive the UDP message on port 8082 the answer, currently, is being sent from port 1515(local) to 8082(remote) and I need to send the message from port 8082(local) to 8082(remote).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `UdpClient` to a local port before you call `Send()`.  The only way to specify the source port is in the `UdpClient`'s constructor, so if you do not know which source port to use until you have received a message first then you will have to wait until then before creating the `UdpClient`.

```vb
Private Sub UdpSend(ByVal txtMessage As String)
    Dim pRet As Integer
    Dim MyUdpClient as UdpClient = new UdpClient(8082); ' <-- here
    MyUdpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(IpRemotaLbl.Text), RemotePortLbl.Text)
    bytCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage)
    pRet = MyUdpClient.Send(bytCommand, bytCommand.Length)
    'Console.WriteLine("No of bytes send " & pRet)
    PrintLog("No of bytes send " & pRet)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, now is working, just one more question, The port defined in the constructor is the local outgoing port or the remote destination port?

Comment: I already answered that above. Please [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35e07es2.aspx).